# Is it possible to convert a simple radtextbox to radnumeric-textbox

Tags: textbox, telerik, servercontrols

Is it possible to convert a simple radtextbox to radnumeric-textbox from codebehind or javascript? I have a dropdown list where i can decide whether the text box should allow only numbers or any character.

Comment: why don't you include both on your page, and hide/disable the one you don't want on the decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize RadMasked Textbox for that purpose.
Simply take RadMaskedTextbox and manipulate the mask according to your requirement in code behind or in javascript.